# Django virtual env issues with Python and Atom

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, atom-editor

I've been all over the site trying to find a solution for a problem i am running into with my virtual environment and the python version being used.

I have installed mini conda
I am on a Mac
I have run the conda create myDjangoEnv python=3.6 conda commmand, and i have activated the env with the conda activate myDjangoEnv command.
I have confirmed that django is installed in the venv and the version is 3.8.4

The problem I am running into is when trying to execute the command python manage.py runserver, I first get the from exc error. When checking python it says it is running 2.7 version in the atom terminal, however when i check my virenv in my normal terminal the python version returns with 3.6.

In the atom terminal, when i execute python3 manage.py runserver, the from exc error goes away but then I run into the ImportError: Django package cannot be found.

Has anyone run into this issue specifically with the Atom server? Is there something I am doing wrong when creating the projects in atom that is tripping the virtual environment and resetting the python version to 2.7?

Comment: You need to activate virtual environment in your Atom terminal.

Comment: virtual environment is activated already, the issue lies within the Atom terminal and the version of python it is pointing to

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the package "script" in Atom?

Answer (score 0):

That issue may be related to you having multiple version of python installed and your terminal is pointing at the wrong one there. I recommend you switch to something like vscode, where you can `ctrl shift P` and select manually the `venv` and `python` interpreter used for the workspace and have your terminal there.

Comment: Thanks, I did end up switching over to PyCharm and was able to get everything to work correctly. With the same venv in Atom it's continuing to point to python 2.7, which is weird because yesterday i wasn't experiencing this issue with Atom.